# Trying to modify the covariance matrix used in the inbuilt kmeans function in r

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, covariance

I am trying to locate where the kmeans function creates and assesses the covariance matrix from the input data set x. I want to override it and give it my own covariance matrix, because the unmodified one struggles with negative eigenvalues.

Another fix would be to find a function that does kmeans clustering with a modified covariance matrix as an inbuilt function, but I haven't found any such function yet.

Thanks in advance!

Function in question:

```
(stat:::kmeans)
```

Comment: Could you provide r example on how far you have figured out the problem?

Comment: It's hard to use an example in r to show how far I've come, since the problem is pretty black and white.

Comment: [K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) does not use the covariance matrix.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the issue with negative eigenvalues without removing the variables when using kmeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KMeans uses *neither* a covariance matrix, nor a distance matrix, nor eigenvalues.

On a proper distance matrix, negative eigenvalues cannot occur.

You must be referring to some other algorithm. Reread kmeans - no covariance matrix, no eigenvalues.